# how to declare string with math operation as variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

PHP:

```
<?php
   $test = "100-12";
?>
```

jQuery:

```
var test = <?php echo $test ?>;
alert(test);
```

in dev tool sources (F12) it looks like this:

```
var test = 100-12;
```

but when already alerted / pass the data in other pages or just alerted the value of test becomes 89 which is the value when 100 is subtracted by 12.

i need the as is value which is 100-12 not the subtracted. how do i stop jQuery from subtracting my string.

i tried String() toString() and even "" +  but nothing works.

Comment: how do you write it from php tol

Comment: If you're echoing from PHP (can't quite tell what your PS means), you can do this: `echo "var test = '101-12';";`, though if you're using variables, it's a little longer `echo "var test = '".$var."-".$var2."';";`

Comment: ---PHP code goes like this:
<code>$test = "101-12";

---in jQuery:
<code>var test = <?php echo $test ?>;

---the problem is in jQuery it subtract the value of 100 to 12

preffered output is 101-12

Comment: @Bobski no im referring to the PHP variable, if in PHP its already `$test = 101-12`, then you have no choice, the arithmetic is already done before it even reaches the browser

Comment: i edit the question sir, its a string in php.

Comment: @Bobski oh okay, i revised my answer tol check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve that (no arithmetic), wrap it with quotes.

So if:

```
<?php

$test = "101-12"; // if this is the origin value

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var test = '<?php echo $test; ?>'; // just put quotes in here as well, so that it does not interpolate it as intergers and do arithmentic
alert(test);
</script>
```

Comment: yes sir, its a string in php, sorry for the late edit of the question.

when alerted normally in jquery, it alert as 100-12

ie alert(<?php echo $test ?>); but when inserted to the jquery variable, thats the time the subtracting is initiating.

Comment: @Bobski you should also add that code on your question which particularly pertains to jquery and lets see, its hard to guess on this end how you're using it

Comment: double " " works, thank you, i guess im a lil bit tired. thanks, better of to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

`var test = "101-12";` will do your job